# Camera preview is distorted when using builtInUltraWideCamera and LivePhotoCapture is enabled

Tags: swift, camera, avcapturephotooutput

When I enable LivePhotoCapture on my AVCapturePhotoOutput and switch to builtInUltraWideCamera on my iPhone 12, I get a distorted image on the preview layer. The issue goes away if LivePhotoCapture is disabled.

This issue isn't reproducible on iPhone 13 Pro.

Tried to play with videoGravity settings, but no luck. Any tips are appreciated!

On my AVCapturePhotoOutput:

```
if self.photoOutput.isLivePhotoCaptureSupported {
    self.photoOutput.isLivePhotoCaptureEnabled = true
}
```

Preview layer:

```
videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
videoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
previewView.layer.addSublayer((videoPreviewLayer)!)

self.captureSession.startRunning()
self.videoPreviewLayer.frame = self.previewView.bounds
```

Result (the picture is mirrored, but it's not a problem, the problem is on the right and bottom edges of the picture):

[image]

Comment: What is the "distorted" part of the image?

Comment: @matt take a look at the right and bottom edges of the screenshot above